# MySQL - 0 rows affected on update when limit is used

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update  ~100000 rows in my database and the query I run is the following:

```
UPDATE urlpool 
SET selfcrawlestate = 0 
WHERE urlpool.url LIKE '%gr.example%' AND urlpool.url NOT IN
(SELECT crawledurl
FROM userscrawled
WHERE userscrawled.crawledurl LIKE '%gr.example%')
LIMIT 400
```

The code above worked for 2-3 times (and updated the values) but now when I run it, it returns a "0 rows affected" message.

When I run another query to check if there are still rows to be updated, it returns again ~100000 rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM urlpool
WHERE urlpool.url LIKE '%gr.example%' AND urlpool.url NOT IN
(SELECT crawledurl
FROM userscrawled
WHERE userscrawled.crawledurl LIKE '%gr.example%')
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause is a "rows matched" restriction. The query will stop when the specified number of rows are found, whether or not those rows are updated.

One possible fix is to include a predicate in the UPDATE, so that rows that don't need to be updated are not matched, e.g.

```
 WHERE ...
   AND NOT ( selfcrawlestate <=> 0 )
 LIMIT 400
```

You can include that same predicate in the query that you are using to check the number of rows that should be updated.

Note that MySQL doesn't increment the "rows affected" counter for rows that don't need to be updated because the value of the selfcrawlestate column is already set to 0.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The MySQL specific **`<=>`** operator is a null-safe equality comparator. It considers NULL values to be valid for comparison, and is guaranteed to return TRUE or FALSE. (This differs from the regular equality comparator **`=`** which will return `NULL` if either of the operands being compared is NULL. (A SQL boolean can have one of the three value: TRUE, FALSE, or NULL).

The boolean expression:

```
NOT ( foo <=> 0 )
```

is equivalent to:

```
( foo IS NULL OR foo <> 0 )
```

Comment: +1 It's worth mentioning what useful but MySQL specific operator `<=>` does

Answer (score 2):

You are limiting the update to 400 rows by `LIMIT 400`. The same rows are updated in each call to UPDATE, and since they are already updated, you get `0 rows affected`. If you remove the limit, all ~100000 rows will be updated.

If you must update in small batches, add some condition that would ensure new records would be updated on each call - for example - `AND selfcrawlestate > 0`.